# -ms-zoom not working in IE 9

Tags: jquery, css, flipclock

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dhtAo

```
.container{
    zoom: 2 !important;
    -moz-transform: scale(2);
    -ms-zoom: scale(2);
    }
```

This code works well in FF and chrome. But in IE 9 only the text is scaled, not the clock. The clock is only shown if i remove the code above.

Anyone knows the reason and the solution for this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IE9 doesn't support `-zoom-`. Use this instead. and test it in your browser and not codepen.

```
-ms-transform: scale(2); /* IE */
-ms-transform-origin: 0 0;
```

Comment: You don't necesarily need the transform-origin, do you?

Comment: OK. Usually when I do transforms I don't do this, and since (I think) the default origin is 50% 50%, it zooms out in the center, which is what I like.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** Just to note: this answer will not work in IE9, but IE8. See [the above answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20276741/ms-zoom-not-working-in-ie-9/20276921#20276921).

Use `-ms-zoom: 2` and not `-ms-zoom: scale(2)`.

Comment: @anvd my bad, this is only supported in IE8. Use thenewseattle's answer -- -ms-transform,